# sharedpreferences stringset value: How to remove in Android Studio.?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have unchecked the checkbox(per item) to remove it . I am using to sharedpreferences with HashSet concept. I want to pass arraylist value from one page to another page. What i do what is my mistake some one help me.

My code is:

```
adapterpage.java

public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "";


@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean isChecked = mainHolder.chekenitem.isChecked();

            // arr=getResources().getStringArray(  mainHolder.txtenimgid.getText().toString());
            //  boolean isChecked = mainHolder.chekenitem.isChecked();
            int i;
            String itemId1 = mainHolder.txtenimgid.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences prefs=view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        try {
            if (isChecked) {


                addmembers.add(itemId1);

                for (j = 0; j < addmembers.size(); j++) {
                    set.addAll(addmembers);
                   edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                   edit.commit();
                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox addmembers[pos] : " + addmembers.get(j) + " Item Id is " + itemId1
                           , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }

                    //   editor.putString("key_name",itemId );
                    // editor.apply();

              //  }

            } else {
                for(int k=0;k<=addmembers.size();k++){
                    if(addmembers.get(k).equals(itemId1)){
                      //  set.remove(addmembers);
                        addmembers.remove(k);
                        edit.remove(addmembers.get(k));
                        edit.commit();

                        break;
                    }


                }
```

Comment: edit.remove("yourKey");edit.commit();

Comment: put your same key name when you want remove sharedpreferences value

Comment: i changed the above code i have 3 array list but i uncheck to 2 nd value the return value came to null

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake here ...

```
 for (j = 0; j < addmembers.size(); j++) {
//set.addAll(addmembers);this will add every time whole data of list into set
    set.add(addmembers.get(j));
                   edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                   edit.commit();
                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox addmembers[pos] : " + addmembers.get(j) + " Item Id is " + itemId1
                           , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
```

And also here while removing change to this...
edit.remove("yourKey");

Comment: i remove and changed the above code but the all value removed i want to specific item value only remove.

Comment: So why are you using SET here just try this...
for (j = 0; j < addmembers.size(); j++) {
                   edit.putString(""+j, addmembers.get(j)).commit();
                     }
And while removing...
 for(int k=0;k<=addmembers.size();k++){
                if(addmembers.get(k).equals(itemId1)){
                    edit.remove(""+k).commit();
                         }}

Comment: i am bind and getting array valu using Set method in another page like ,Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("yourKey", null);
       ArrayList<String> addapterarraylist = new ArrayList<String>(set);
       for (String temp : addapterarraylist) {
        System.out.println(temp);           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),temp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "";
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        boolean isChecked = mainHolder.chekenitem.isChecked();

        // arr=getResources().getStringArray(  mainHolder.txtenimgid.getText().toString());
        //  boolean isChecked = mainHolder.chekenitem.isChecked();
        int i;
        String itemId1 = mainHolder.txtenimgid.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences prefs=view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    try {
        if (isChecked) {


            addmembers.add(itemId1);

            for (j = 0; j < addmembers.size(); j++) {
                set.addAll(addmembers);
               edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
               edit.commit();
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox addmembers[pos] : " + addmembers.get(j) + " Item Id is " + itemId1
                       , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }

        } else {
            for(int k=0;k<=addmembers.size();k++){
                if(addmembers.get(k).equals(itemId1)){
                    edit.remove("yourKey");
                    edit.commit();
                }


            }
```

what you have to do is that whenever the item is checked you are simply clearing the shared pref value. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all, i got the solution in my code working fine.

```
        String itemId1 = mainHolder.txtenimgid.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences prefs=view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        try {
            restart:
            if (isChecked) {
                addmembers.add(itemId1);
                for (j = 0; j < addmembers.size(); j++) {
                    set.addAll(addmembers);
                   edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                   edit.commit();
                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox addmembers[pos] : " + addmembers.get(j) + " Item Id is " + itemId1
                           , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }

            } else {

                //editor.remove("username").commit();
                for(int k=0;k<=addmembers.size();k++){
                    if(addmembers.get(k).equals(itemId1)){
                        addmembers.remove(k);
                        edit.remove("yourKey");
                        set.addAll(addmembers);
                        edit.putStringSet("yourKey", set);
                       edit.commit();
                      break restart;
                    }


                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.toString();
        }
```

the code is working fine to me.